# STRING_TOO_LARGE String in Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, string, kotlin

When I added plugins to support the **Kotlin** in my project, Then after it read large string from my project's **string.xml** file. It gives me following error below.

error: string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as '**STRING_TOO_LARGE**'.

Comment: I have the same problem but when using support lib 28 alpha. 
I found this https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/104

Comment: check if you have a large `vector drawable` as suggested in the post above

Comment: I have declared the long string in string.xml

Comment: What gradle version are you using? There might be a bug with 3.2 beta (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110853846). Try downgrading to 3.1.3 and see if that helps.

Comment: Downgrading Gradle Build Tools to 3.1.0 (classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0') fixed it for me

Comment: @AnilUgale did you find a solution?

Comment: I found a solution to examine the apk and should point you to the problem. See my answer below.

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229987/android-studio-with-java-compiler-error-string-too-large-to-encode-using-utf-8

Answer (score 10):

When working with vector resources, you simply need to find and divide a string that is longer than 32kb, in my case, it was a complex path which I simplified a little to match the criterion of 32kb

Comment: It is absurd that Android doesn't do a better job at specifying where the problem is. I have a project of dozens of thousands of files, it's impossible to manually search which file has the problem

Answer (score 9):

<strike>This is an issue with the gradle plugin.</strike>

<strike>If you upgrade the plugin to `3.3.0-alpha06` or later and upgrade gradle to `4.9` it should work. It's not ideal since it is alpha, but it fixed the issue for me.</strike>

Add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` to the top of any resource .xml file that is missing it.

Comment: yeah, it works..thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is not really a Kotlin question, it's related to the build tools. This didn't happen on Build Tools 27 (Gradle 3.1) but happened for me after upgrading to Build Tools 28 (Gradle 3.2).

The solution is posted here [STRING_TOO_LARGE Java compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229987/android-studio-with-java-compiler-error-string-too-large-to-encode-using-utf-8?noredirect=1&lq=1).

You can use AAPT (from the android sdk/build-tools) to examine the APK and look for the offending string:

```
// Linux/Mac
./aapt dump --values resources MyAppName-regular-debug.apk | grep -B 1 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'

// Windows
aapt dump --values resources MyAppName-regular-debug.apk | grep -B 1 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'
```

Comment: Man... I just can't consider this an answer, but a workaround. Downgrading version ins't a solution

Comment: This is not a solution!

Answer (score 5):

It seems that a common cause for this is having a Stripe in your app/build.gradle, seems it has a vector file being read as a string longer than 32kB.

To solve this, change your stripe version to something after 7.0.0, which is where they fixed it. Current version of Stripe is 8.1.0.

Comment: This fixed my problem!

Answer (score 2):

**Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart . This solved my problem.**